# Large AWS RDS MySQL update drops connection

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, query-performance

I am attempting to perform a mass update on table containing 279,480 rows. The update must query another table 1,113,770. The update will select a set of records and and then calculate their sum and apply the result to a column in the table being updated.

The query works perfectly for single rows, but when applying to the full table, it fails with:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

This is being done inside a function. Here is the actual query. The invoiceheader table is the smaller table:

LEGACYINVOICENO  is the PK for invoiceheader. SELLINGDEPARTMENT is also an indexed field as is the POSTDATE in the invoiceheader.

```
SELECT SUM(EXTENDEDPRICE)+SUM(TAX) FROM invoicedetail 
    WHERE LEGACYINVOICENO IN(
    SELECT LEGACYINVOICENO FROM invoiceheader 
    WHERE SELLINGDEPARTMENT = _department
    AND POSTDATE < _postdate
       AND LOTJOB_ID = _ljID) into _balance_used;
```

Updated Information. 
Here is a sample of the query actually working using a single instance:

```
 SELECT SUM(EXTENDEDPRICE)+SUM(TAX) FROM invoicedetail 
    WHERE LEGACYINVOICENO IN(
    SELECT LEGACYINVOICENO FROM invoiceheader 
    WHERE SELLINGDEPARTMENT = 2
    AND POSTDATE < '2013-06-06'
       AND LOTJOB_ID = '45497100FOXLAND1640')
```

The execution plan indicates that the nested loop is resulting in a full table scan of the invoiceheader table. This seems a likely cause of the problem, but I'm not sure how I need to go about optimizing the inner query.

For testing purposes, I've simplified the query:

```
 SELECT SUM(EXTENDEDPRICE)+SUM(TAX) FROM invoicedetail 
    WHERE LEGACYINVOICENO IN(
    SELECT LEGACYINVOICENO FROM invoiceheader 
    WHERE LOTJOB_ID = '45497100FOXLAND1640')
```

LEGACYINVOCENO is the PK and LOTJOB_ID is indexed, but the WHERE clause is still resulting in a full table scan.

Comment: Maybe your server is crashing. Check the error logs.

Comment: Depending on the number of results from the inner query, that could get nasty.  Have you considered a join instead?  Have you looked at the query plan?

Comment: It's conceivable that a MySQL connection could drop during a long running query. You probably should start by optimizing the query. We could do a bunch of guesswork. But instead you should read this, paying special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Then you should [edit] your question to give more details.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've tried to update the question with some relevant data. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Is this a one-time task?  Or a recurring task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`, change to either a `JOIN ... ON`.  This is likely to avoid the table scan.

Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what you are working with.

For large `UPDATEs`, [*chunk it*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).